# How to set the default program to open knitted Word files from RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, default, docx, libreoffice

I have Windows 7+ PCs with both LibreOffice and MS Office installed.
I'm trying to figure out how to make RStudio to open DOCX file produced via *Knit to Word* in LibreOffice Writer and *not* MS Word.
Is there an option to choose the default viewer for Word files?
One can easily set the default program for PDF files:

[image: RStudio options]

but I cannot find a similar option for DOCX files neither in GUI, nor by looking at the output of `Sys.getenv()`.

P.S. LibreOffice is set systemwide as the default program for opening office formats, but it appears that RStudio doesn't check system preferences.